# cannot implicitly convert 'void' to 'decimal'

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Getting this error  at `futureValue = this.CalculateFutureValue(futureValue, monthlyInvestment, monthlyInterestRate, months);`and I'm having trouble figuring out how to fix it. When I look up the error online most of the answers say to make the method decimal instead of void so it can have a return type.

But in part of the requirements for the code "rework the CalculateFutureValue method by making it a void function and adding a fourth parameter representing the future value amount to be returned by this method."

```
private void btnCalculate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {            
            decimal monthlyInvestment =  Convert.ToDecimal(txtMonthlyInvestment.Text);
            decimal yearlyInterestRate = Convert.ToDecimal(txtInterestRate.Text);
            int years = Convert.ToInt32(txtYears.Text);

            int months = years * 12;
            decimal monthlyInterestRate = yearlyInterestRate / 12 / 100;
            decimal futureValue = 0m;

            futureValue = this.CalculateFutureValue(futureValue, monthlyInvestment, monthlyInterestRate, months);

            txtFutureValue.Text = futureValue.ToString("c");
            txtMonthlyInvestment.Focus();            

    }
```

/

```
private void CalculateFutureValue(decimal futureValue, decimal monthlyInvestment, decimal monthlyInterestRate, int months)
    {

        for (int i = 0; i < months; i++)
        {
            futureValue = (futureValue + monthlyInvestment) * (1 + monthlyInterestRate);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass the variable by reference:

```
private void CalculateFutureValue(ref decimal futureValue, decimal monthlyInvestment, decimal monthlyInterestRate, int months){ ... }
```

and

```
this.CalculateFutureValue(ref futureValue, monthlyInvestment, monthlyInterestRate, months);
```

See [this documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0f66670z.aspx).

If `futureValue` had not been initialized with a value before passing it to `CalculateFutureValue`, the `out` keyword would have needed to be used in place of `ref`.

Comment: Could also be eluding to the [out](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t3c3bfhx.aspx) keyword.

Comment: `futureValue` is initialized before it is passed, so it doesn't really matter which one is used.

Answer (score 3):

Here is what they mean by the requirement: instead of this

```
decimal ComputeSomething(decimal x, decimal y) {
    return x*x + y*y;
}
...
decimal result = ComputeSomething(10.234M, 20.5M);
```

do this:

```
void ComputeSomething(decimal x, decimal y, out res) {
    res = x*x + y*y;
}
...
decimal result;
ComputeSomething(10.234M, 20.5M, out result);
```

Note the `out` qualifier in front of the additional parameter `res`. This means that the parameter is "output", i.e. your method must assign it some value before completion.

The assignment to `res` inside `ComputeSomething` will become an assignment to variable `result`.